When running a planning sequence with an AMDP function inside, a dump occurs
I wrote a test class and tried to run it from RSPLAN.
I created a planning function in RSPLF1 with these settings:

"without blocks"
"process empty records"

I enter the planning sequence in RSPLAN, but when I start it, I get a dump:
UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION
CX_RSR_X_MESSAGE
SAPLRRMS
BW4-AE
I created a class using the standard interfaces IF_RSPLFA_SRVTYPE_IMP_EXEC and IF_RSPLFA_SRVTYPE_TREX_EXEC, and ES_DATA - completely replicates the aggregation level on which my planning sequence is based.

My full class:
CLASS zicl_rspls_script DEFINITION
  PUBLIC FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC.

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_amdp_marker_hdb.
    INTERFACES if_rsplfa_srvtype_imp_exec.
    INTERFACES if_rsplfa_srvtype_trex_exec.

    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF es_data,
        infoprov  TYPE rsinfoprov,
        icaccfem  TYPE /bic/oiicaccfem,
        icbunit   TYPE /bic/oiicbunit,
        icesuvers TYPE /bic/oiicesuvers,
        icfipasst TYPE /bic/oiicfipasst,
        icfipproj TYPE /bic/oiicfipproj,
        icinesuvr TYPE /bic/oiicinesuvr,
        icrstep   TYPE /bic/oiicrstep,
        icvrplfem TYPE /bic/oiicvrplfem,
        ifkeyfig  TYPE /bic/oiifkeyfig,

      END OF es_data.

    " Table type
    TYPES et_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF es_data WITH EMPTY KEY.

    CLASS-METHODS r_calc
      IMPORTING VALUE(i_view) TYPE  et_data
      EXPORTING VALUE(e_view) TYPE  et_data.

ENDCLASS.


CLASS zicl_rspls_script IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD if_rsplfa_srvtype_imp_exec~execute.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD if_rsplfa_srvtype_imp_exec~finish_execution.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD if_rsplfa_srvtype_trex_exec~init_and_check.
    e_trex_supported = rs_c_true.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD if_rsplfa_srvtype_imp_exec~init_execution.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD if_rsplfa_srvtype_trex_exec~trex_execute.
    DATA lr_sql_script     TYPE REF TO if_rspls_sql_script.
    DATA lv_procedure_name TYPE string.
    DATA lt_iobj_param     TYPE if_rsr_pe_adapter=>tn_t_iobj_param.

    lr_sql_script = cl_rspls_session_store_manager=>get_sql_script_instance(
                        i_r_store = i_r_store ).

    lr_sql_script->get_parameter_values(
      EXPORTING i_r_param_set             = i_r_param_set
                i_para_name_for_procedure = 'R_CALC'
      IMPORTING e_procedure_name          = lv_procedure_name
                e_t_iobj_param            = lt_iobj_param ).

    lv_procedure_name = 'ZICL_RSPLS_SCRIPT=>R_CALC'.
    r_s_view-view = lr_sql_script->execute_sql_script(
                        i_view                  = i_view
                        i_t_iobj_param          = lt_iobj_param
                        i_proc_name             = lv_procedure_name
                        i_sql_script_returns_ai = abap_true
                        i_r_msg                 = i_r_msg ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD r_calc BY DATABASE PROCEDURE FOR HDB
                LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
                OPTIONS READ-ONLY.
    E_VIEW = SELECT * FROM I_VIEV;
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

If I start debugging, it crashes inside the call to the method execute_sql_script, marked below with -->:
    lv_procedure_name = 'ZICL_RSPLS_SCRIPT=>R_CALC'.
--> r_s_view-view = lr_sql_script->execute_sql_script(
                        i_view                  = i_view
                        i_t_iobj_param          = lt_iobj_param
                        i_proc_name             = lv_procedure_name
                        i_sql_script_returns_ai = abap_true
                        i_r_msg                 = i_r_msg ).

If I go further inside execute_sql_script, there are some standard functions written by SAP. Since the dump is standard, I think there is an error somewhere in the declaration/syntax, but I can't find it.
The program does not even enter the method R_CALC.
Below is a source code snippet from the dump message
   *... keine Meldung, wenn kein Handler initialisiert
        IF g_active IS INITIAL.
          return.
        ELSE.
          l_type = 'W'.
        ENDIF.
    
        " if i_r_previous was passed, also print out the exception
        IF i_r_previous IS BOUND.
          CALL FUNCTION 'RRMS_EXCEPTION_HANDLING'
            EXPORTING
              i_r_exception = i_r_previous
              i_msgty       = l_type.
        ENDIF.
    
        CALL FUNCTION 'RRMS_MESSAGE_HANDLING'
          EXPORTING
            i_class  = 'BRAIN'
            i_type   = l_type
            i_number = '299'
            i_msgv1  = i_program
            i_msgv2  = i_text.
    
      ELSE.
        DATA: l_text  TYPE string,
              l_repid TYPE syrepid.
    
        l_repid = i_program.
        l_text  = i_text.
    
  -->  RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_rsr_x_message
          EXPORTING
            text     = l_text
                     program = l_repid
                     previous = i_r_previous.
      ENDIF.
    
    ENDFUNCTION.

l_text = MATERIALIZE_VIEW-03
l_repid = CL_RSPLS_SESSION_STORE_MANAGER

Contents of system fields
SY-SUBRC 0
SY-INDEX 1
SY-TABIX 0
SY-DBCNT 1
SY-FDPOS 40
SY-LSIND 0
SY-PAGNO 0
SY-LINNO 1
SY-COLNO 1
SY-PFKEY STATUS_2000
SY-UCOMM
SY-TITLE View scheduling sequence
SY-MSGTY E
SY-MSGID RSR_PE
SY-MSGNO 005
SY-MSGV1 2.048
SY-MSGV2 column store error: alterPlanningSession error:
SY-MSGV3 [38001] Session ‘2024122811113532_9870660’ not
SY-MSGV4 valid.#Last error: Condition ‘pi-
SY-MODNO 0
SY-DATUM 20241228
SY-UZEIT 143532
SY-XPROG SAPLRSR_TRANSACTION_HANDLING
SY-XFORM XAB_WFLUSH

I've been trying to find something about the error
RSR_PE 005 2.048. On the saphelp forum there was a solution to change the field names in the internal table to different ones from the aggregation level, but unfortunately it didn't help me.
I will be glad for any help/advice.

Bug due to a typo in the procedure name? (one space in front of ' ZICL_RSPLS_SCRIPT=>R_CALC') Note that the dump contains more information about the error, but you have given only the 4 first lines. The exception object CX_RSR_X_MESSAGE also contains more information about the issue.

@SandraRossi
Regarding the problem with the space in the procedure name, it came up while editing the question on the site. The procedure name itself does not contain a space in the system, and I have corrected it here.
Regarding CX_RSR_X_MESSAGE, I have included the information I could find in this post. Unfortunately, I am not very experienced in analysing ABAP dumps. If you could advise me where to look, I would appreciate it.

I have fixed your question ('ZICL_RSPLS_SCRIPT=>R_CALC'). Could you attach the short dump then?

It's i_r_previous that contains closer exception details (which may itself refer to a previous one and so on). The SAP note 2426974 - Detailing UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION error in BWIP also explains how to get more information (ask your SAP administrator an "S-User" to view it). There is also the SAP note 2866051 - PE error 2,048: column store error: alterPlanningSession error: [38001]
